# Activemq consumer can not reconnect automatically

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

> jms.brokerurl=failover:(tcp://ip:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0)?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch\=2&randomize\=false&initialReconnectDelay\=50&timeout\=3000

Spring configuration

```
<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="maxConnections" value="10"/>
    <property name="maximumActive" value="10"/>
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

```
<bean id="receiveContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="QUEUE_NAME"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="productUpdateListener" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: There is no any log found in consumer server, but Activemq admin page shows number of consumer is zero.

Comment: Currently, the log level is INFO.

Comment: when do you expect the reconnection to happen ? After a failure ?

Answer (score 0):

PooledConnectionFactory closes sessions/consumer connection after the consumer has processed messages.Hence the consumer count keeps reducing.

If you are using multithreaded environment its better to use CachingConnectionFactory. But this has some drawbacks as it caches the consumers so if a consumer hangs the client would keep pinging the stalled consumer without knowing that its connection is idle.

Exact solution for your problem, using JMS template is hard to find but you can manually create new connections by checking that if a connection has been closed by using `connection.start()` or `connection.createConnection` methods.